# Change Dragonfly (Gem) File Permissions (i.e. to 0664)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-permissions, dragonfly-gem

Dragonfly creates files by default with permissions set to 0644

From https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/lib/dragonfly/temp_object.rb#L116

```
def to_file(path, opts={})
  mode = opts[:mode] || 0644
  prepare_path(path) unless opts[:mkdirs] == false
  if @data
    File.open(path, 'wb', mode){|f| f.write(@data) }
  else
    FileUtils.cp(self.path, path)
    File.chmod(mode, path)
  end
  File.new(path, 'rb')
end
```

It seems like other permissions can be provided. But how?

Where it's called there is no options hash being passed in.

From https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/lib/dragonfly/file_data_store.rb#L107

```
content.to_file(path).close
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is not as clean as I like it to be, since it's coupled against implementation details of Dragonfly, I've found a way by means of guerilla patching...

In `config/initializers/dragonfly.rb` I added

```
class Dragonfly::Content
  def to_file(path)
    umask = File.umask(02)
    val = temp_object.to_file(path, mode: 0664)
    File.umask(umask)
    val
  end
end
```